# Calculate SHA1 of CD-ROM on MacOS X

Tags: macos, mac, compact-disc, crc, sha1

How do you calculate the `sha1` of a CD-ROM disc under MacOS X?

On Linux (RedHat) I use `sha1sum /dev/cdrom`.

How do I do the same thing on Mac using `openssl sha1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out which `dev` is your DVD drive, enter `mount` and look for the volume name of the DVD you inserted. Alternatively, look it up in *Disk Utility » File » Get Info » Entry Path*.

Then you need to unmount the volume (*not* eject the device). Open *Disk Utility*, select the volume (**not** the device) in the list, right-click, and select *Unmount "Name of Disk"*.

Then you can use

```
$ openssl sha1 /dev/disk6
SHA1(/dev/disk6)= ee099db39922cf2d14282a8957f9243e092809e8
```

Comment: I don't have a Linux system here to compare results. Please let me know if these are wrong. Also try `disk6s1` or another of the "sub-devices" in that case.

Comment: To get the `md5` check sum, the same steps are required. `md5sum` doesn't work on devices, so use `cat /dev/disk6 | md5` instead.